# scrolling in modal twiiter-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have 2 modal in twitter-bootstrap

```
<body>
<!--very long scrollable content in body-->
```

**first modal with long height:**

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="adminsetting" data-modal-index="1" tabindex="1" >...</div>

<div class="modal fade in" id="adminsetting2" data-modal-index="2" tabindex="2" >...</div>


</body>
```

---

when I call first modal in body section,the modal shows. and I can scroll the modal.

again, when I call second modal in **first modal** (without hide first modal), the second modal shows and I can scroll it.

everything is normal when show modals.

But when hide second modal and return to first modal. I couldn't scroll first modal else. (instead of it the body section will be scroll)

how can fix that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found more dynamic code try this

Paste this code into jQuery ready function

```
        $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            if(($(".modal").data('bs.modal') || {}).isShown){
                $('body').addClass('modal-open');
            }             
        })
```